# Sublime Text URL handler for ubuntu

Tags: sublime-text

How can I make sublime text 2 respond to `txmt` url scheme in ubuntu? This has been possible in OSX through [subl-handler](https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler) and in Windows through [SublimeProtocol](https://bitbucket.org/sublimator/sublimeprotocol/overview).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I see you have asked this question on both SO and AskUbuntu, so I answer here too, but don't know if one of these shouldn't be closed]

I asked me the same question today, seeing the txmt protocol with "better_errors" gem for Rails.

I search a long time but found nothing, so I tried to make it by myself.

I write an [article and my blog](http://blog.byscripts.info/2013/02/txmt-protocol-and-sublime-text-2-english.html), but I copy it here, for "future-proofness" :

## Step 1

Create the file `/usr/share/applications/sublime-handler.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text 2 URL Handler
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Handle URL Scheme txmt://
Exec=/home/<your_user>/bin/sublime-handler %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/txmt;
Icon=sublime-text-2
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Sublime Text 2 URL Handler
```

## Step 2: Update the MIME-types database

```
$ sudo update-desktop-database
```

## Step 3: Create the ~/bin/sublime-handler file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

request=${1:23}               # Delete the first 23 characters
request=${request//%2F//}     # Replace %2F with /
request=${request/&line=/:}   # Replace &line= with :
request=${request/&column=/:} # Replace &column= with :
sublime-text-2 $request       # Launch ST2
```

Then make it executable : `$ chmod +x sublime-handler`

## Step 4: Test a txmt:// file

If that dosen't work, say me, I'll try to help you.

Comment: on step3 : do i need to create file  with name `sublime-handler` on `/bin/` folder and need to write that code?

Comment: The tilde `~` means `home` directory. `~/bin/sublime-handler` is exactly the same directory than ``/home/your_name/bin/sublime-handler``

Comment: there is no `/bin` folder in `~`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a utility made for this: https://github.com/algorich/sublime-url-handler

Download the [latest release](https://github.com/algorich/sublime-url-handler/archive/master.zip), unzip it, and run the following commands:

```
cd sublime-url-handler-master
bash install
```